# Do not open "GNU Emacs" buffer when launching Emacs

Tags: buffers, start-up

**"GNU Emacs" buffer** is opened automatically when launching Emacs(both terminal and GUI), and I have to kill that buffer everytime. It's boring.

How to turn **"GNU Emacs" buffer** off autimatically when launching Emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
```

into your init file. Then you start-up in the scratch buffer. You can use the variable `initial-buffer-choice` to set up your own preference.